# My Menu items not seen in Wordpress Database

Tags: database, wordpress, menu

I am newbie to WordPress.

I want to add my custom menu items my menu Home Page. That is why i look for place in Wordpress database where menu items(including menu labels) are stored. But problem is - I can't find my menu elements in my Wordpress database. I found similar topic ("Where are Custom Menus saved in the Database for Wordpress 3.0") but I didn't find anything can help me. I found only title of my menu ("Home Page") and its details, but nothing about pages attached to the menu! OK. This is my menu I want to find in my database(name:WP):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9ZL0.jpg

I checked ALL tables from my database WP. These are picks from table wp_post. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEbR5.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbpWG.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/10AIR.jpg

I didn't find anything.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: Here is a pretty good answer:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78316/wordpress-default-menu-in-database

Comment: Thank u for reply.1st set of commands is useful. But 2nd one (to find menu items like "Home Page", "Login", "Logout", "Users", "Customer Page" etc.) doesn't show me menu names. "Post name" column in wp_post table after execution of this set of commands is empty. And that is a problem....